# <hex. prefix for the XML generated tag using Cobol

Tags: xml, cobol

Can someone please suggest?

<hex.Nm> The output xml is generated with <hex.Nm>, not sure what is the issue with the copybook declaration below,

```
  04 Dbtr. 
    05 Nm PIC X(140).
```

Comment: This one misses completely the code and the expectation compared to the output.
Please click on "edit" on [your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545050), copy-paste the relevant parts here (allowing you to also see how formatting is done), providing a full self-contained **Q**uestion for a full self-contained **A**nswer.
... and maybe take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)...

Comment: Even with the question being answered by cschneid it would still be useful to edit the question showing more code and the data (hex dump or similar) to have a good question for people facing different issues (and would likely lead to up-vote of it instead of down-votes).

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us your code, but I'm guessing you didn't code an "On Exception" phrase in your XML Generate statement, and triggered an XML-CODE of 417 which is [documented](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=material-xml-generate-exceptions) as...

> Element character content or an attribute value contained characters
> that are illegal in XML content. XML generation has continued, with
> the element tag name or the attribute name prefixed with 'hex.' and
> the original data value represented in the document in hexadecimal.
> Any TYPE IS CONTENT specification is ignored, and the item is treated
> as an element.

IBM's documentation for their mainframe products is pretty good.  It's worth your time to become familiar with it.  None of these products is small.  Taking the time to learn where and how things are documented will serve you well.  Much better, in fact, than posting a question to the Internet every time you encounter something unexpected.